# PHP displaying an image from Cloudinary triggers an Uncaught...ConfigurationException

Tags: php, cloudinary

Greeetings

I'm using `PHP 8.1.2` and `Cloudinary`

I'm still new to `Cloudinary` with `PHP`.

I have a script that uploads an image to `Cloudinary`. It works just fine. On the flip-side, I don't know how to display an image that is stored on `Cloudinary`. I've found very little help online. I don't know what `Cloudinary` files/classes I need to include/require. I'm doing something wrong.

If anyone can point me to a good how-to tutorial or show me how to do this, I would be most greatful.

```
# show-image.html

<?php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

use Cloudinary\Cloudinary;

// image folder/name on cloudinary
$image_on_cloudinary = 'student_images/carter-ski-jump-big.jpg';

$cld_image = new Cloudinary();
$cld_image->imageTag($image_on_cloudinary);  // line 9 referenced in error

?>
```

I get this error:

```
[30-Jan-2024 21:30:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Cloudinary\Exception\ConfigurationException: 
Invalid configuration, please set up your environment in /home/sacnomad/livingmuaythai.com/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/src/Configuration/Configuration.php:293
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sacnomad/livingmuaythai.com/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/src/Cloudinary.php(59): Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration->validate()
#1 /home/sacnomad/livingmuaythai.com/students/show-image.html(9): Cloudinary\Cloudinary->__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/sacnomad/livingmuaythai.com/vendor/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/src/Configuration/Configuration.php on line 293
```

In my image upload script, I have this set up, which I also tried in my show-image page, minus the `Cloudinary upload lines`.

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/cloudinary_creds.php');
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

$cc = new CloudinaryCreds();

use Cloudinary\Cloudinary;
use Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration;
Configuration::instance( $cc->get_cloudinary_url() );

// Use the UploadApi class for uploading assets
use Cloudinary\Api\Upload\UploadApi;

$upload = new UploadApi();

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

if( isset($action) && $action=="Submit" ){
  if ( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']) ) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $image_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];

    $image_array = $upload->upload($tmp_name, [
                                 'public_id' => $image_name,
                                 'use_filename' => TRUE,
                                 'folder' => 'student_images',
                                 'overwrite' => TRUE ] );

    print "<p>Public_ID: ".$image_array['public_id']."</p>";
  }
}
...
```

As noted, this works just fine for uploading an image. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass the config when instantiating a Cloudinary object so that the image_tag call will generate the image url to an existing account. For example:

```
  //call the image
  $image_on_cloudinary = 'student_images/carter-ski-jump-big.jpg';

  $config = Configuration::instance();
  $config->cloud->cloudName = 'my_cloud_name';
  $config->cloud->apiKey = 'my_key';
  $config->cloud->apiSecret = 'my_secret';
  $config->url->secure = true;

  $cld_image = new Cloudinary($config);
  $cld_image->imageTag($image_on_cloudinary);
```

The above should generate the image URL.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work. I get the same error.  I can post my code as an edit to my initial post, it you want to see it?

Comment: @JohnCowan, I made the edit. Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That works.  I accepted your answer. Thank you so much. Adding `$config` to the `new Cloudinary()` call fixed it.  I needed to add `print` to your imageTag line, but it works.  `print $cld_image->imageTag($image_on_cloudinary);`  FINALLY!!!